# Problema al subir múltiples archivos con bootstrap-fileinput

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap

Buenas tardes! tengo un problema con `bootstrap-fileinput`. 
Cuando subo varios archivos, en PHP, solo veo el último! en el PHP probé poner únicamente `print_r($_FILES);` y me sale lo que ven en la siguiente imagen:
[image: Solo aparece en el array la ultima imagen]
osea, que solo me esta enviando la ultima imagen. Tengo entendido que en [name]
 debo tener otro array con los cada uno de los nombres de las 3 imagenes, y de igual forma en los otros valores ([type],[tmp_name],[error],[size])
aquí les pongo el código javaScript que utilizo para iniciar la libreria:

```
var inputB = $("#inputB");
inputB.fileinput({
    language: "es",
    uploadUrl: "pruebasubida.php", // server upload action
    uploadAsync: false,
    showUpload: false, // hide upload button
    showRemove: false, // hide remove button
    showCancel: false,
    minFileCount: 1,
    maxFileCount: 20,
    maxFileSize:1024000,
    maxFilePreviewSize: 10240,
    allowedPreviewTypes: ['image', 'html', 'text', 'video', 'audio'],
    fileActionSettings: {
      removeClass: 'btn btn-xs btn-default"  style="margin-top:0;"',
      uploadIcon: '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload text-info" style="display:none;"></i>',
      uploadClass: 'btn btn-xs btn-default"  style="display:none;"',
      zoomClass: 'btn btn-xs btn-default"  style="display:none;"'
    },
    uploadExtraData: function(){
      return {
        "user" : user,
        "pass" : pass,
        "msj"  : $("textarea#cfMessage1").val(),
        "mail" : $("input#cfMail").val()
      }
    }
})
```

No se que otra información darles, desde ya muy agradecido por su ayuda!

Aquí agrego el html del input:

```
<input id="inputB" name="file_data" type="file" multiple="true" class="file-loading">
```

Comment: agrega el html de los file input las imagenes no ayuda.

Comment: ahí esta, la idea de la imagen era que vean la respuesta desde PHP que obtengo cuando hago el print_r en la variable $_FILES

Comment: no hermano esto no funciona así, las imágenes de lo que muestra tu php para nosotros son irrelevantes ya que no sabemos que código hay detrás...  y por ende no podemos determinar el error en el codigo que devemos adivinar...

Comment: " en el PHP probé poner únicamente print_r($_FILES);" perdón por no ponerlo mas claro, pensé que esto explicaría que en el PHP solo esta esto: `<?php print_r($_FILES);?>`

Comment: el php no tiene nada que ver esta correcto lo que tienes que hacer es modificar el html o hacer el handle para modificar el nombre de los inputs... asi como te lo presento en la respuesta de abajo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error esta aqui:

```
name="file_data"
```

deberia de ser:

```
name="file_data[]"
```

Comment: ok, voy a probar, pero no entiendo porque, podrías explicarme? muchas gracias!

Comment: el concepto de array debes presentarlo en el html, si quieres que llegue de esa manera al php, es como decirte variable[0],variable[1],variable[2] pasa lo mismo con el html....

Comment: ahhhh no sabia, muchísimas gracias! funcionó perfecto!

Comment: si se te complica mucho hay otras maneras. de hacerlo pero si o si tienes que modificar el atributo name en cada input ya que si lo repites literalmente sin "[ ]" no te va a funcionar.